# Shows status 'Connecting' in the webRTC after accepting the call

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc

I have implemented the pub Nub WebRTC video calling code and able to call one device to another, however, after I accept a call on one device, the camera previews get opened on both the devices yet the status shows 'CONNECTING'.

It keeps like this for a long time. What am i doin wrong?

I have logged in to the pubnub admin dashboard, created the keys. Please help.[image: It shows Connecting]